# TornadoFX: Compare 2 form values in ValidationContext

Tags: javafx, kotlin, observable, tornadofx

**In tornadofx**, I am trying to validate if two values of inputs in a form equal. I followed [this](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide/blob/master/part1/11.%20Editing%20Models%20and%20Validation.md#ad-hoc-validation) guide and everything works as expected. But I encountered that I have no way how to check if the two values in inputs equal.

For example, let's say I want to create the simple registration form where I have to check if the 2 passwords equal. What I tried was:

```
val validator = ValidationContext()

validator.addValidator(this, this.textProperty()) {
    if(!password!!.isEqualTo(it).get()) //password1 != password2 -> does not work
        error("Passwords do not equal")
}
```

I looked into the [login example](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-samples/tree/master/login) hoping I would find help in the example code but without success.

Is there a way to compare the inputs in the validation context? If so how?

**EDIT:** This does work but I don't think it is the desired way to check the inputs in the validation context. Is there a better way?

```
if (password.get() != password2.get()) 
    error("Passwords do not equal") //Returns the error message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create validators for each field so that they compare against the other field. Then you need to make sure to re-evaluate the validator for the other field when a field is changed. Make sure to include `focusFirstError = false` to avoid the focus to shift when you make a change in the input fields.

```
class DualValidationForm : View() {
    private val vm = object : ViewModel() {
        val text1Property = bind { SimpleStringProperty() }
        val text2Property = bind { SimpleStringProperty() }
    }

    override val root = form {
        fieldset("Make sure both fields have the same value") {
            field("Text 1") {
                textfield(vm.text1Property) {
                    validator {
                        if (it == vm.text2Property.value) null else ValidationMessage("Not the same!", ValidationSeverity.Error)
                    }
                    vm.text1Property.onChange {
                        vm.validate(focusFirstError = false, fields = vm.text2Property)
                    }
                }
            }
            field("Text 2") {
                textfield(vm.text2Property) {
                    validator {
                        if (it == vm.text1Property.value) null else ValidationMessage("Not the same!", ValidationSeverity.Error)
                    }
                    vm.text2Property.onChange {
                        vm.validate(focusFirstError = false, fields = vm.text1Property)
                    }
                }
            }
            button("You can click me when both fields have the same value") {
                enableWhen(vm.valid)
                action {
                    information("Yay!", "You made it!").show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thats, +/- what I expected (more in my edited question), there isn't a really neater way of doing such things is there?

Comment: Not that I can think of :)